# Java Kerberos authentication using Active Directory User Principal Name

Tags: java, authentication, kerberos, jaas

I'm trying to switch from Simple LDAP authentication to `GSSAPI` authentication.

I'm using `Krb5LoginModule` to perform the authentication when setting username to user's `UPN` which looks like `user@suffix` where suffix is not domain name.

Authentication fails as Krb5LoginModule assumes that the name format is `principal@realm`.

Is there any option to pass the username which contains @ to the Krb5LoginModule so it will use the full user name without extracting realm from the username?

Using sAMAccountName works but I don't have user's sAMAccountName but UPN.

User logon to Windows works using `UPN` and the only difference I see in the network captures is that during Windows login name-type which is used is `KRB5-NT-ENTERPRISE-PRINCIPAL` and `KerberosString` includes full `UPN` name as opposite to `KRB5-NT-PRINCIPAL` and `KerberosString` with truncated `UPN` name sent by Java.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Java does not support enterprise principals (type 10) (principal canonicalization). MIT Kerberos does. You are out of luck.

Comment: Thank you. I had to switch to sAMAccountName.